# How to remove parameter constraint definitons to a variable so that Asserts become less crowded in Rhino.Mocks?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, rhino-mocks

How can I exlude the parameter constraints

```
Arg<DateTime>.Is.Equal(departureConstraint)
    Arg<DateTime>.Is.Equal(arrivalConstraint)
```

from the assert below

```
mockBookingService.AssertWasCalled(
                m =>
                m.BookShuttle(Arg<DateTime>.Is.Equal(departure)

, Arg<DateTime>.Is.Equal(arrival)));
```

so that I can re-write it in a more friendly way like:

```
mockBookingService.AssertWasCalled(
                m =>
                m.BookShuttle(departureConstraint, arrivalConstraint));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a more succinct syntax you can use:

```
Arg.Is(departureConstraint)

mockBookingService.AssertWasCalled(m =>
            m.BookShuttle(Arg.Is(departure), Arg.Is(arrivalConstraint)));
```

Or, since you have actual values for all of your parameters, You can just remove the parameter constraints altogether.

```
mockBookingService.AssertWasCalled(m =>
            m.BookShuttle(departure, arrivalConstraint));
```